# Update box without setTimeout

Tags: notifications, real-time, box

I was making a notification system with a box on the rightside. I want that this box update himself when user receive a new notification from other users,
[this is the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rafnt.png)

I want to do this update without using the setTimeout that javascript offers. I think that if I've a lot of users and I use the setTimeout every 5/10 seconds it can be create some problems, that I don't want.

I was thinking to use the long polling, but I never used that. So do you have some suggestion? In few words I want that when an user Y writes a comment in the post of user X, this last user receive an update of him notification's box.

What do you recommend me? If you have also some tutorial where I can learn how to do that I'll appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Please be more clear that this is using JavaScript and provide some sample code.

Comment: Ok, so. I've an ajax request that call a file .php that insert the comment in database. I wrote a function that add a notification to the database and I call this function in the file that I call in the ajax request.     
$notification->addNotification($post_id, $user_id, $post_select_assoc['user_id'], "0");
This is the function: post_id is post_id, user_id is my user id and the assoc is the user that write the post. The 0 is fore "read" or "unread".
I want that when I insert a data, my notification's box update..without a setTimeout javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use React (https://reactjs.org/) with Firebase (firebase.google.com). Google's firebase is a realtime database and if you fetch data from it in your React app, it will update itself every time there is a change.